# Is SVM uses latent variables when input variables/features are superior than 3

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svm, dimensionality-reduction, latent-variable

I was wondering if SVM uses some kind of latent variables / latent space when inputs variables/features are superior than 3.

In fact I know that SVM uses dimension - 1 (a curve in 2D, a plane in 3D, ...).

But the fact is that I can explain 95% (variance) of my dataset with PCA on 3 dimensions and I would like to say that I can use these same features for SVM because there are meaningful with PCA, so why not with SVM ...
So yeah using PCA to conclude that inputs are significant, so I can work with. Especially with a rbf kernel.

(NB: I already tried to train a SVM on PCA principal components, a disaster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually take latent variables to have a different meaning.
SVMs use feature transformations: you can express them as (possibly infinite) polynomial expansions of the original features under any kernel.
Latent variables, on the other hand, are usually meant to represent unobserved/unobservable probabilistic relationships.

Under this notion, neither is PCA based on latent variables.
PCA extracts feature transformations (linear combination of features), just like the SVM.

Latent variable models similar to PCA are Probabilistic PCA and Factor Analysis.
You can compare them to see how they differ.

Comment: Hmm ok Thanks a lot ! So PCA features extraction are comparable to SVM ?

Comment: @T_Henry no, not even if the same kernel is used. The reason is that PCA extracts features that improve reconstruction of inputs, while SVM extracts feature that improve the prediction of a dependent variable.